# Is there a version of bsxfun that works on structure arrays?

Tags: matlab, struct, bsxfun

Why can I do this:

```
a = [1 2];
b = [3 4];
bsxfun(@(ai,bj) ai + bj, a, b')
% 4     5
% 5     6
```

But not this:

```
a = struct('x', {1 2});
b = struct('x', {3 4});
bsxfun(@(ai,bj) ai.x + bj.x, a, b');
% Error using bsxfun
% Operands must be numeric arrays.
```

And does a replacement function exist that works in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a general solution<sup>*</sup> but for your particular example it is easy to convert your structure array to a numerical array *inside* bsxfun, by using [*comma-separated-list generator syntax*](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html), and then using your original anonymous function, i.e.

```
>> bsxfun(@(ai, bj) ai+bj, [a.x], [b.x]')
ans =
     4     5
     5     6
```

and this should still leverage the computational efficiency conferred by `bsxfun` (as opposed to the much slower "`repmat`+`arrayfun`" approach, for instance).

---

*<sub>e.g. it might not work as intended if your field contains an array instead of a scalar, since the expansion to a comma-separated-list will be different</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately, the reason I was after this was to use two fields from the struct

Comment: Well, depending on the exact nature of your problem, you may still be able to use this technique if your fields have the right format. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

A hacky workaround:

```
function res = bsxfun_struct(f, A, B)
    % best way to ensure our output size matches the behaviour of bsxfun is just to call it
    dummy = bsxfun(@(ai, bj) ai+bj, zeros(size(A)), zeros(size(B)));
    res_size = size(dummy);

    % repeat the matrices as needed
    Arep = repmat(A, res_size ./ size(A));
    Brep = repmat(B, res_size ./ size(B));

    % now we can just apply the function pairwise
    res = arrayfun(f, Arep, Brep);
end
```